# How to configure one to zero and one to one relationship in fluent api with different PK and FK

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, ef-fluent-api

I am a beginner and learning fluent API from tutorials. I read the some of the already given SO solution about **1-0, 1-*** but I could not understand them properly. I simply want to use **fluent API** to set up **One to One and One to Zero** Relationship provided no convention followed.

House and Room (terrible example)

Requirement:

```
1. One House can have zero room or ONE room MAX.
2. One Room must be inside a house.
3. If a room is deleted House SHOULD NOT Get Deleted
4. If a House is getting deleted and there is a room then
  User should first delete the room then only House should be allowed to be deleted.


public class House
{
    public int HouseId { get; set; }
    public string HouseName { get; set; }
    public virtual Room Room { get; set; }
}

public class Room
{
    public int RoomId { get; set; }
    public string RoomName { get; set; }
    public int HouseId { get; set; }
    public virtual House House { get; set; }
}
```

So, Room cannot exist w/o a House but a House can exist w/o a room. Also, in case if a House has room, it can only have one.

```
         dBModelBuilder.Entity<House>()
            .HasOptional(f => f.Room)
            .WithRequired(s => s.House);
```

I saw some solution but they are telling to set the `PK and FK same`. But I **don't** want to do that. Is there a way to achieve what I want **w/o setting PK and FK same**. I DO NOT want the HouseID to be PK of my Room class. Also in my case principal is House and Dependent is Room. Do I need to add soemthing like `"Optional Dependent" or "Optional Principal"`. Can some one please guide me I am a beginner.

Also, Do I need go remove navigation property from any of my MODELS? Is that extraneous?

How to tell EF to use HouseId of Room class as FK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also in my case principal is House and Dependent is Room

Then you are on the right track with

```
modelBuilder.Entity<House>()
    .HasOptional(f => f.Room)
    .WithRequired(s => s.House)
```

because in EF one-to-one relationship the required side is always the principal. You need to specify the principal/dependent only when both sides are required or both sides are optional.

The problem is your requirement of using different FK in the dependent entity than the PK, which is the default EF model for such relationship (so called [Shared Primary Key Association](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-3-shared-primary-key-associations)), and is supported well. From the other side, one-to-one FK association is supported, but with some limitations. More specifically, explcit FK property like `HouseId` in your `Room` is not supported - there is no `HasForeignKey` fluent method for this type of configuration, and it's by purpose. I can't say why, but it's a fact. If you try playing with `[ForeignKey`] attribute, you'll get quite unexpected results, so don't do that.

Remove that property:

```
public class Room
{
    public int RoomId { get; set; }
    public string RoomName { get; set; }
    public virtual House House { get; set; }
}
```

and use `Map` fluent API with `MapKey` to specify the FK column name:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<House>()
    .HasOptional(f => f.Room)
    .WithRequired(s => s.House)
    .Map(c => c.MapKey("HouseId"));
```

This will give you the desired database table design (although there is no way to constrain `HouseId` column to be unique, except manually editing the migration).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, Sir, can you tell me one more thing. In case if I have two tables ROOMONE and ROOMTWO, both has similar relationship with House i,e one to one/zero. Then how will I handle it using the basic EF approach. Can you put that example too. Because of that fear only I thought of having a separate FK, Because my HOUSE will have one to one/zero with multiple table

Comment: Can you kindly give me a basic example of having SAME PK FK but using multiple table related to House

Comment: So, suppose I want to have SAME FK and PK then how will I handle it in case of multiple tables. Are you understaning my doubt sire?

Comment: Yes. But there is no problem as soon as House is the principal, because the only affected are the PK of the dependents. In the original model, the `RoomId` will not be identity, but simple `int`, and will be marked as `PK` of `Room` and FK to `House`. The same will happen if you have other one-to-one extensions of `House`. So to use shared PK, simply remove `HouseId` and use your original fluent setup.

Comment: In case you are not constrained by existing database, I would suggest using the Shared PK approach. Btw, EF Core has not such limitations and supports both scenarios well (although still uses Shared PK by default).